# How to copy my local db to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm working on a simple Rails (activeRecord based) application, and i'm testing in locally.

Now it's time to move online, but... do i need to insert all the records again in the app's db? I hope not!

Do you know a if is it possible to make a copy of my entire local db and import it in heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Which database? mysql? 2. what is heroku?

Comment: sqlite3. Heroku is a great ruby on rails hosting service! I suggest you to try it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

erm, using the Heroku CLI

```
heroku db:push
```

job done, built into Heroku - will magically transpose your local DB whether it be sqlite, mysql, postgres to Heroku's shared postgresql db.

Comment: Worked just fine for me. You have to have the taps gem installed.

Comment: What if the remote db is not empty? ` push from LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE to REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE
 REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE must be empty.

Comment: [If not empty: Heroku pg:reset REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset)

Answer (score 3):

Try `yaml_db` gem

> https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

Comment: and totally unnecessary when it comes to Heroku.